# Multires baked textures breeak for tangent space view after being exported

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

After baking normal map and ***exporting it***, it shows very visible seams in tangent space https://prnt.sc/b82A7hwSItby

However, this does not happen if you use memory stored bake normal map, the error occures only after exporting it [image]
[image]
[image]

So I suspect, that some kind of a data loss happens after exporting it, that makes these seams to appear. The question is - how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the answer comes right after posting the question, despite being stuck with this problem for a day.

The problem was in multires baking, since it creates empty space between islands.

When saving as EXR, I presereved alpha channel by saving it as RGBA. Padding did not help at all, so saving it as RGB fixes the issue.